# using linq and entity framework to iterate over database data

Tags: asp.net, database

I read that in some books they use linq to sql  and entity framework..

Whats so good about them?!!?

They are slow.. especially linq to sql. Does entity framework have any benefit that make it worth learning?!?

I strive to make the site as fast as I can, and I dont use disconnected data access much

consider that my goal is to make the site run as fast as it can

Comment: If you want speed don't use an ORM. ORM's are made for rapid development.

Comment: lol..what does it mean, rapid development... why to sacrifice speed?!!?

Comment: Because sometimes you have a limited window to develop something and performance isn't a requirement. As ken mentioned the extra layers of abstraction has a cost. Also the ORM will build the SQL query as it sees fit. It may or may not be optimal for what you're doing. There's a large setup cost that can be mitigated by using an ORM system.

Comment: Okay, I will avoid that.. what is better Entity Framework or Linq to Sql, in terms of performance and rapid development

Comment: I *believe* that Linq-2-Sql is faster and Entity Framework has more features. They are both good for rapid development. If you only need to create a simple data access layer, Linq-2-SQL should work fine.

Comment: One other note. Depending on your dataset size and complexity most of your performance improvements will be done in the database. Indexes, partitions, parallel reads/writes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM frameworks like **Linq-to-Sql** and **Entity Framework** will almost always implement an abstraction layer between the program code and database SQL statement. This layer's job is to parse the code's syntax **into** a SQL statement.

So, if your ultimate goal is increased speed, it would be smart to avoid that layer.

Comment: I thought the same.. But some programmer, told me if you use Entity framework in the right way, it wont slow the web applicaiton..so I thought whether there are exceptions where Entity framework isnt slow or Entity Framework isnt slow if you can use it correctly

Comment: Using it "in the right way" can be tricky, considering Entity Framework won't always be able to optimize queries for speed (especially when you consider that some database back-ends can implement non-standard SQL to improve performance). That said, there are plenty of web applications running in the field that have accepted this penalty for the increased speed of development that an ORM provides.